# Android ConstraintLayout Margins not working correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

As seen in the picture, the view boxes are rendered at the current position, but the content is not. The text views as well as the image views are rendered as if there weren't any margins. When I run the app, they also aren't rendering properly(second image). I don't know what could be causing it.[image: Editor Preview]
[image: Live Demo]

EDIT: I forgot to include my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.android.stundenplanexample.dynamic_recyclerview.ExpandingCardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    android:layout_margin="12dp">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_expand_more_black_24dp"
            android:id="@+id/card_expand_toggle"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            card_view:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Medium"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_width="42dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/card_expand_string"
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/extra_information"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            tools:text="ToleToleToleInfo"
            card_view:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
            card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</com.example.android.stundenplanexample.dynamic_recyclerview.ExpandingCardView>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see one definite problem and one potential problem.

The definite problem is that your `textView3` specifies these attributes:

```
android:layout_margin="8dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
```

This does not set the top/start to 16dp and the end/bottom to 8dp. It simply causes the `marginTop` and `marginStart` attributes to be ignored.

The potential problem is that you specify

```
android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
```

but do not also specify `marginLeft`. If you want to support pre-API 17 devices, you need to specify both `marginStart` and `marginLeft` (assuming you remove the `margin` attribute).

Comment: The margin's weren't set manually, but by the design view. I will try it anyway, thanks

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I guess I didn't see it because I'm normally working with css and html, where this does work.

Comment: Do you know where I can report this as a bug (since the editor clearly isn't rendering it correctly)

Comment: You do NOT need to add both start/end AND left/right margins. android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd are sufficient.

Comment: @Shroud as I said in the answer, start/end were added in API level 17, so if you're supporting API 16 or earlier these attributes will be ignored and you should use left/right. If you do both left+start or right+end, on 17+ the start/end will take precedence.

Comment: @BenP. Firstly, I don't think there's much reason to support pre API 17 devices at this point, since that is less than 2% of users.  If for some reason you did want to however, I'd suggest that you define a separate version of the layout file, and stick the one with layout_marginStart and End inside a values-v17 folder.  That will make things less confusing, and prevent any potential conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set start and end constrains before setting start and end margins. I had same problem and it worked after setting end constrains .